# Linked UserControl dependency properties do not sync

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

In my project I have two custom user controls. One simple numeric control called `NumericUpDown`. And a numeric control grid called `NumericUpDownGrid`. Both have defined dependency properties as follows:

For the `NumericUpDown` the XAML code is:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox x:Name="txtNum" x:FieldModifier="private" Margin="5,5,0,5" Width="50" Text="{Binding Value,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Button x:Name="cmdUp" x:FieldModifier="private" Margin="5,5,0,5" Content="˄" Width="20" Click="cmdUp_Click" />
                <Button x:Name="cmdDown" x:FieldModifier="private" Margin="0,5,0,5"  Content="˅" Width="20" Click="cmdDown_Click" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

And the C# property defined as follows:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueDependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double), typeof(NumericUpDown));

public double Value {
    get { return (double)GetValue(ValueDependencyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueDependencyProperty, value); }
}

public NumericUpDown() {
    InitializeComponent();
    Value = 0.0;
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Based on the above simple control I need to make a grid of those controls. However instead of resolving each element I can bind an array of values so that I don't have to code all the updates.

Therefore the code for a grid of those components is the following:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Width="20">A</Label>
        <control:NumericUpDown x:Name="A" Value="{Binding Values[0],Mode=TwoWay}"></control:NumericUpDown>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Width="20">B</Label>
        <control:NumericUpDown x:Name="B" Value="{Binding Values[1],Mode=TwoWay}"></control:NumericUpDown>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Width="20">C</Label>
        <control:NumericUpDown x:Name="C" Value="{Binding Values[2],Mode=TwoWay}"></control:NumericUpDown>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Similarly the C# code for the dependency property and the constructor is:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValuesDependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Values", typeof(double[]), typeof(NumericUpDownGrid));
public double[] Values {
    get { return (double[])GetValue(ValuesDependencyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValuesDependencyProperty, value); }
}

public NumericUpDownGrid() {
    Values = new double[] { 0.5, 0.0, 0.0 };
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Now I would expect that when I push either the cmdUp or cmdDown button, the value change inside the single `NumericUpDown` would be reflected in the relevant array of my `NumericUpDownGrid`. Since those are bounded. But this is not the case. Any help would be much appreciated.

I need this since will binding this `NumericUpDownGrid` to data from my application higher up the chain. I am expecting that this binding will propagate downwards to a single element when bound. Additionally any change by a single `NumericUpDown` should be propagated back to the array used at a higher level.

Comment: `Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"`

Comment: That's wrong. It must be `Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}` (assuming it is a UserControl), and you have to remove the DataContext assignment `this.DataContext = this;`. If you explicitly set the DataContext like this, a Binding like `<control:NumericUpDown Value="{Binding Values[0],Mode=TwoWay}"/>` expects the `Values` source property in the NumericUpDown control.

Comment: @Clemens could please elaborate or point me out to a documentation source?

Comment: The elaboration is in the answers of the marked duplicate questions - and several other similiar ones. For the DataContext in general, there is online documentation. In case you found `DataContext = this;` in a blog post or tutorial, be aware that there is a lot of garbage on the internet. A valid place for an explicit assignment of the DataContext is in a Window or Page. In a control, it is always wrong, because it break DataContext-based bindings of the control's properties.